# use of regular expressions with python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a script that takes a list of words from one file and try to search for those specific words in another file and if the specific word is found then the entire line is printed.
The problem is that i want in the search file only the words that i'm looking for will be matched 
exemple : if i have to search for the word "word123", i don't need to have 
the hit "word12345" to be found just the first one corresponding to the exact word i wrote

This is the code :

```
for line in searchfile:
    for word in keywords:
        if re.search ("^word$" , line):
            print(line.strip(), file = new_file)
            break
```

The result is always an empty file

Comment: Do you also have such words in your list as *-word-* or *=start=*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if re.search (r"\b"+word+r"\b" , line):
```

You need to use `\b` or `word boundary` here .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the regex

```
"^" + word + "$"
```

try:

```
r"^.*\b" + word + r"\b.*$"
```

Comment: if the line has any other words in it, though, the ^ and $ could make it fail.

Comment: Not with the two .* patterns.

Comment: @strbizhev - you need to use raw strings for the regex pattern.  I'll edit my answer so that isn't missed.